# How can i add spaces to my XML file from the rss feed

Tags: php, html, xml, rss

Hello i have the following code im my rss feed page

```
$rss_txt .= '<item>';
$rss_txt .= '<title>' .$row['created_at']. '</title>';
$rss_txt .= '<link>http://localhost/report_profile.php?id='.$id.'</link>';
$rss_txt .= '<description>' .$row['title'].$row['area']. '</description>';
$rss_txt .= '</item>';
```

and i want after `$row['area']` to include another variable `$row['user_id']` but the xml file print them in arow without space and isnt very clearly to read

Comment: What's inside `$row['title']` , `$row['area']` and `$row['user_id']` ? Have you tried putting a simple space beetwen area and user_id, like `$row['area'] . ' ' . $row['user_id'] . '` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little difficult to understand but based on the comment of @1nflktd I would suggest something like this if it is a simple space you want:

```
$rss_txt .= '<item>';
$rss_txt .= '<title>' .$row['created_at']. '</title>';
$rss_txt .= '<link>http://localhost/report_profile.php?id='.$id.'</link>';
$rss_txt .= '<description>' . $row['title'] . $row['area'] . ' ' . $row['user_id'] . '</description>';
$rss_txt .= '</item>';
```

If you would like to add something other than a space I would suggest that you just add the text you like in between the quotes (Between $row['user_id'] and $row['user_id']):

```
$rss_txt .= '<item>';
$rss_txt .= '<title>' .$row['created_at']. '</title>';
$rss_txt .= '<link>http://localhost/report_profile.php?id='.$id.'</link>';
$rss_txt .= '<description>' . $row['title'] . $row['area'] . 'YOUR TEXT GOES HERE!' . $row['user_id'] . '</description>';
$rss_txt .= '</item>';
```

Comment: Thank you all guys that worked fine i was a little dizzy and couldnt think clearly ..